# How do I resolve data for a schema type that implement an interface in GraphQL?

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, java-8, graphql, graphql-java

I’m trying to develop a spring boot graphQl service using graphql-java-8 library. I’m fetching data from a web-service, the response I get from the service is a bit like dynamic for which I have to introduce graphQl interface in my response graphQl schema.

```
extend type Query {
    search(
        name: String,
        category: String
    ): [ResultOne]
}

interface ResultOne {
    name: String
    content: String
}

type Fish implements ResultOne {
    name: String
    content: String
    weight: Float
}

type Fruit implements ResultOne {
    name: String
    content: String
    Color: String
}

type Toy implements ResultOne {
    name: String
    content: String
    description: String
}
```

To wiring my model with graphQl framework,

```
return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
    .wiringFactory(new WiringFactory() {})
    .type(
          TypeRuntimeWiring.newTypeWiring("ResultOne")
          .typeResolver(env -> {
              if(env.getObject() instanceof Map) {
              Map object = env.getObject();
              if (object.containsKey("name") && object.get("name").equals("fish")) {
                return (GraphQLObjectType) env.getSchema().getType("Fish");
              } else if (object.containsKey("name") && object.get("name").equals("fruit")) {
                return (GraphQLObjectType) env.getSchema().getType("Fruit");            
              } else if(object.containsKey("name") && object.get("name").equals("toy")) {
                return (GraphQLObjectType) env.getSchema().getType("Toy");  
              } else {
                return null;
              }
          } else {
             return null;
          }
      })
  )
  .build();
```

So, type resolving issue is also fix a way, not sure it’s ideal or not. For data binding I’m not sure how do I do that in graphQl’s recommended way. I would like to add that, I’ve a single End-Point and single fetcher for the whole API. Data are fetched in a single request and don't want to call twice as I already have whole response. I had to resolve the type at runtime and wire the data for implemented model. So far data are fetched perfectly and the values are also coming till the interface against my query, but appeared null for interface implemented model part e.g: Fish, Fruit & Toy in this example. My question is how do I manupulate dynamically resolved type data for the java library?

Feel free to ask me any question regarding this issue.

Sample query:

```
{
  search() {
    ResultOne {
      name
      content
      ... on Fish {
        weight  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Corresponding response that I'm currently getting:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": [
     {  
     "resultOne": [
          {
            "name": "Salmon", 
            "content": "Frozen Food",
            "weight": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "extensions": {
    "Total-ResponseTime": 23020,
    "resultOne-Time": 22683
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using the `TypeResolver` correctly and the code seems fine. But I don't understand the problem you're having? Is it that you get nulls in the response where you don't expect them? Can you show the query you fire?

Comment: I've appended a sample query and corresponding response in my question detail part. The problem is just with the implemented part where it comes null for all of its attribute I mention in my query.